# How to use TestNG in Eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testng

I have successfully installed TestNG in eclipse through Help->Install New Softwares but while configuring build path, it is not visible in Add Libraries.

The TestNG option is not even visible to create TestNG class.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are confusing two different things. The TestNG that you can install from Eclipse the way you described is installing the TestNG plugin for eclipse. If you want to actually use TestNG to run your tests, you need the TestNG library.

You can download it and manually add to your classpath or, if you are using Maven, add it as a dependency to your pom file.